# How to set nil index for collection_select in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In the [Rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html), they show that using a `select` you can change the option values from the default numbering to be the actual values that are shown (code block 6). Is there any way I can do that with a `collection_select`?

My Rails code is:

```
<%= f.label :category %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :category, Costume.all, :id, :category, include_blank: true %>
```

And it produces the HTML:

```
<select id="search_category" name="search[category]"><option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">shirt</option>
  <option value="2">pants</option>
</select>
```

What I want is:

```
<select id="search_category" name="search[category]"><option value=""></option>
  <option value="shirt">shirt</option>
  <option value="pants">pants</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From code block 6,

```
collection_select(:post, **:category_id**, Category.all, :id, :name, {disabled: lambda{|category| category.archived? }})
```

You can try to set the `:category_id` to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that doesn't seem to be working. I added some edits to make it more clear what I'm asking. Thanks!

Comment: It was this: `f.collection_select :category, Costume.all, :category, :category, include_blank: true`